# How get accumulative counts of data by division

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server

Suppose I have a set of data of a range of number. I want to count the occurrence of the data by dividing from the highest power to the lowest point by 12.

```
declare @highest decimal(9,5) = 72, @lowest decimal(9,5) = 12
```

--suppose the highest point of data is 72 and the lowest point is 12

```
declare @division decimal(9,6) = (@highest - @lowest)*12

select floor((data - @lowest) / @division)*@division+@lowest AboveLine, 
       count(data>floor((data - @lowest) / @division)*@division+@lowest) Counts
from Dataset
group by floor((data - @lowest) / @division)
order by AboveLine desc
```

i have checked the script many times. the engine just doesn't run the code and complains

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

What's wrong with the code?
Is there a more intelligent way to write it without using **group by**? It's a very messy and inflexible way to do a query.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i'm running SQL server

Comment: Count `(` and `)`. Same number?

Comment: absolutely the same

Answer (score 0):

What is this?

```
count(data>floor((data - @lowest) / @division)*@division+@lowest)
```

I assume you intend something like:

```
sum(case when data > floor((data - @lowest) / @division) * @division + @lowest
         then 1 else 0
    end) as counts
```

Comment: i eventually want to get percentage of the whole set. does it allow me to do SUM(...)/count(*)?

Comment: I run your script once. i don't understand the mechanics. Although the engine runs it, it's not accumulative. it counts the occurrence each grid. It's not what i want.

Comment: @TrioCheung . . . If you actually want to do something, then ask a *new* question.  This question is about a *syntax* error which is now answered.  Your new question should explain the logic and provide sample data and desired results.