# SQL doesn't allow > condition in count?

Tags: sql

Say I have a dataset containing a lot of numbers.
I can do a query as

```
select count(*) from Dataset
```

But SQL doesn't allow me to make a > comparison within the count function

```
select count(num>10) from Dataset
```

Why's that?
I know `select count(*) from Dataset where num > 10` will do the job.

I'm here just simplifying my question I have [posted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59356750/how-get-accumulative-counts-of-data-by-division/59356805?noredirect=1#comment104908395_59356805), because I have a more complicated query applying the > comparison in which **where** cannot be used.

How can I use the > within `count` without using where?

Comment: What do you think `count(num>10)` is supposed to mean?  What is wrong with using `where`?

Comment: you need to understand the proper `SQL syntax and structure` back to the drawing board

Comment: Are you looking for `count(*) filter (where num > 10)`?

Comment: if you read my previous question, you will know why i want to write this syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59356750/how-get-accumulative-counts-of-data-by-division/59356805?noredirect=1#comment104908395_59356805

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `CASE` expression inside `COUNT` which will return `NULL` when the condition is not true i.e.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN num > 10 THEN 1 END) FROM Dataset
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to run directly a SQL Query, you can use filter operations in COUNT using GROUP BY HAVING, like that:

```
SELECT myId FROM myTable Group By myId HAVING Count(*) > 10
```